# Need help Kotlin Coroutines, Architecture Component and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, retrofit2.6

I'm trying to wrap my head around the mentioned components and I can't get it right. I want to do something very simple: Fetch data from the network and present it to the user. Currently am not yet caching it as am still learning new Coroutine features in Architecture components. Every time app loads I get an empty model posted, which seems weird.

My API is get hit fine and response is 200 which is OK.

Below is what I have attempted:

POJO

```
data class Profile(@SerializedName("fullname") val fullName : String.....)
```

Repository

```
class UserRepo(val context: Context, val api: Api) {

    suspend fun getProfile(): Profile
    {
        val accessToken = ....
        return api.getUserProfile(accessToken)

    }
}
```

API

```
interface GatewayApi {
    @GET("users/profile")
    suspend fun getUserProfile(@Query("access-token") accessToken: String?): Profile
}
```

ViewModel

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val usersRepo = UserRepo(application.applicationContext, Apifactory.Api)
    val userProfileData = liveData{
        emit(usersRepo.getProfile())
    }

    fun getProfile() = viewModelScope.launch {
        usersRepo.getProfile()
    }
}
```

Finally my fragment's relevant code

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.userProfileData.observe(this, Observer<UserProfile> {
     //it is having nulls
 })

//trigger change
viewModel.getProfile()
```

Comment: "Every time app loads I get an empty model posted" -- this suggests that Retrofit is having difficulty converting the server response into the designated object. You might consider adding an OkHttp logging interceptor to see what the raw response looks like and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: brilliant idea. I will add that. Do you find any fault with my current code? I will appreciate criticism also apart from what I asked

Comment: The snippets that I see seem OK.

Comment: Thanks for checking!

Comment: I recommend wrapping `userRepo.getProfile()` in a try/catch and then see if an error is being caught.

Comment: @CommonsWare answer turned to be the cause. I used wrong model and GSON had hard time serializing it. Can you post as an answer so that I accept it? Thank you user2836202, thanks for the comment, but there were no exceptions thrown in this case

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question, as you can explain your circumstances and findings better than I can. I am glad to hear that you got it working!

Comment: Thank you. I always love to give due credence to the owner. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added HTTP requests and responses (thanks to @CommonsWare for pointing that out) and it happened I had used a different model than I was supposed to use. The correct model that mapped the JSON response was `ProfileResponse` and as you can see in my posted code, I used Profile instead. So all fields were empty as Gson could not correctly serialize JSON into `Profile` object.

All the credit goes to @CommonsWare for pointing that out in comment.